# What is the situation that this sentence says?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Several lines had been deleted from her speech.

It is an example sentence of "delete" above.
What situation would be this sentence referring to?

> 1. Several lines had been deleted when she scanned her speech before she began.
> 2. Someone wrote down her speech and missed several lines by mistake.
> 3. Your opinions..

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: This sentence gives you no idea of how or when they got deleted, just the fact that they had.

Any answer is speculation.

Comment: *Missing* several lines is not the same thing as *deleting* them. The lines could have been deleted by *mistake* but they cannot have been deleted if they never existed in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, "speech" would appear to refer to a pre-written piece of text to be read out, or given as "a speech".

As "deletion" is a deliberate act of *removing something*, and "had been" refers to a *past* action, it suggests that some lines were removed from the text *before it was read*.

It the lines were never there in the first place and had been left out either on purpose or accidentally, the more appropriate word would be "omitted". If they were for a certainty left out by accident then the word "missed" would be the most appropriate. This would be the case if details were left out of the script before it was handed to the speaker, or if the speaker chose to omit certain written lines during the reading.

Answer (score 0):

The more I think about it, the more I feel that the situation is too vague for *absolute* certainty.   In my opinion, test questions should either be indisputable, or they should not be on the test.

The question hinges around the exact meaning of the word "deleted" in the example.  A *deletion* is normally a deliberate act.  If it was accidental, then the example should say so explicitly.

In this case, we know for certain *someone* edited Susan's speech beforehand.  We can imagine Susan assuming some lines were "deleted", presumably by the copyist, when in fact the copyist simply *overlooked* those lines.  There's no way to know the reasons for the "deletion" from the information given.

I suppose it's possible that the teacher wants you to think about the situation and explain why there's not enough information, though.